# MongoDB external script file

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb

I am using mongoDB and am curious to whether you can import scripts like you can in MySQL:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword database < script.sql
```

Can you do this with mongoDB?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass a list of JS files to the **mongo** JavaScript shell and those will get executed:

```
$ echo "print('hello');" > test.js
$ ./mongo test.js
MongoDB shell version: 1.3.2-
url: test
connecting to: test
hello
```

You can use the normal **mongo** command line arguments if you need to specify a specific db, username, or password like you do in your above example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a library like [PyMongo](http://linux.downloadatoz.com/pymongo/) to access the db, but after installing you should be able to script aggainst the mongoDB very well using python.